# Are there $n$ disjoint, connected sets whose union is $\mathbb{R^3}$ which translate to each other?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

When thinking the other day about grids, it occurred to me that if you take each point $p$ in $\mathbb{Z^3}$ and place a cube of sidelength 0.5 with $p$ as its center and then connect the cubes by extruding their faces to meet all their "nearest neighbours" (i.e all points with one of their coordinates $+$ or $-$ $p$'s value), you get a 3D grid with the nice property that its complement in $\mathbb{R^3}$ is connected.

It then occurred to me that its complement was in fact a copy of itself translated by a specific vector. **My question**: Is there a way of splitting $\mathbb{R^3}$ into *3* disjoint connected sets, so that you can make with one all the others through translations?

If this *is possible*: Can we do this with $n$ sets?

If this *isn't possible*: Can we make a construction that works for $n$ sets if we further allow the operations of rotation and scaling?

REMARK: It also occurs to me that if it isn't possible to make it work in 3-space, then it might work in higher dimensions... This intuition comes from the fact that in 2-space, the complement of a grid is a bunch of disjoint squares (i.e. the complement is *not* a connected set), while in 3-space there is "enough room" for its complement to still be connected.

Comment: Usually, the definition of connected includes being open. If this is the case, then you cannot split $\mathbb{R}^n$ into disjoint connected sets, because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected.

Comment: @mathworker21 *Usually*, it doesn't include that.

Comment: Can you explain better your cube configuration for $\mathbb{R}^3$?  I don't understand how you extrude the faces an connect the cubes at all.

Comment: @Batominovski: The upshot is that the cubes are in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOSV8.png) sort of arrangement, where the spheres in the image shown should be substituted for cubes such that the square crossection of the "pipes" between the cubes and the cubes themselves are of equal area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some preliminaries in $\Bbb R^2$:
Let  $$S_0=\{\,(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid 0\le y<1\,\}$$
and $$T_0 =\{\,(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid 0\le x+y<1\,\}.$$
Then the translates of $S_0$ by all integer multiples of $(0,1)$ are a tiling (covering with pairwise disjoint parts) of $\Bbb R^2$. The same holds for the translates of $T_0$ by all integer multiples of $(0,1)$.
Now  let
$$S=\bigcup_{k\in n\Bbb Z}(S_0+(0,k)),\qquad T=\bigcup_{k\in n\Bbb Z}(T_0+(0,k))$$
and with $n\ge 2$, for $0\le i<n$, let
$$A_i=\{\,(x,y,z)\mid (z>0\land (x,y-i)\in S)\lor z\le 0\land (x,y-i)\in T)\,\}.$$
Then the $A_i$ are a tiling of all of $\Bbb R^3$ and are translates of each other. Moreover, they are readily seen to be path-connected.